# giving whitespace as value of table of parameters in scenarios of Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I use the Cucumber framework, WebDriver and Java for auto testing. For parametrized tests I use table of parameters. And I don't know how to give whitespace as value of parameter. And I become to use keyword - WHITESPACE. My example bellow:

**First method**

```
Scenario Outline: checking of sending feedback
Given User wants send feedback
When User enters to the feedback field the following text:
"""
<suggestion>
"""
And User presses on the 'Send' button
Then User should see message <message>

Examples:
|suggestion|message|
|| Suggestion's field is empty!|
|\n| Suggestion's field is empty!|
|\n text text text| Successfuly send!|
|WHITESPACE| Successfuly send!|
```

then in step definition:

```
@When("^User enters to the feedback field the following text:$")
public void user_enters_feedback(String textOfSuggestion) {
      textOfSuggestion.equals("WHITESPACE")?" ":textOfSuggestion;
      new pageSuggestion().inpSuggestion.sendKeys(textOfSuggestion)
}
```

**Second method for same scenatio**

Also I try to use [Transformer](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/Transformer.html), but it did not work.

I created class

```
class MyTransformer extends Transformer<String> {
    public String transform(String value) {
         value.equals("WHITESPACE")?" ":value;
         return value;
     }
}
```

then in step definition:

```
@When("^User enters to the feedback field the following text:$")
public void user_enters_feedback(@Transform(MyTransformer.class) String textOfSuggestion) {
      new pageSuggestion().inpSuggestion.sendKeys(textOfSuggestion)
}
```

**How I can do it better for reusing with another steps or adding new keywords?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to do anything at all.  Consider this

```
Scenario Outline: Something
  Given I have "<param>"
  ...    
  Examples:
  |param|
  |     | #spaces
  ||      #empty
```

This happily prints "Empty..." when param is blank/empty

```
@Given("^I have \"(.*?)\"$")
public void i_have(String arg1) {
  if (arg1.trim().equals("")) {
    System.out.println("Empty...")
  }
}
```